# Determine if attribute has frontend value

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, frontend, ce-1.9.2.2

In a little generic exporter I am currently writing I am exporting all products and their attributes that reside in the `data` array.

For some attributes, it is necessary to translate their integer value into their frontend value (manufacturer, brand ...).

The best way I found to do that so far is this:

```
$storeviewProduct->getResource()->getAttribute($key)->getFrontend()->getInputType()
```

However, for all attributes that do not have a frontend value, a FATAL ERROR is thrown:

```
Call to a member function getSource() on boolean in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 1385
```

It seems that this happens whenever I try to check if this attribute has a frontend value to display. However, I cannot seem to determine if I have to check any frontend value without the FATAL ERROR.

I'd prefer not to tinker with the error settings of my script or install a custom FATAL ERROR handler to catch just this error. I hope that there's a way without iterating over all attributes first, then reading the values for the attribute from the product instead of just iterating over the data array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this questions is still relevant. But this worked for me:

```
$key = '...' // Key definition

$attr = $storeviewProduct->getResource()->getAttribute($key);

$value = $attr->getFrontend()->getValue($storeviewProduct);

if($storeviewProduct->getData($key)) {
  // Output
}
```